# udp socket with c++ and windows API

Tags: c++, multithreading, udp, winsock

I'm writting an UDP server for a game. 
Do you know if is possible to have multisocket in UDP on one port ? or I must use dynamic port (one socket = one port) ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Using SO_REUSEADDR...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Using SO_REUSEADDR
>
> The SO_REUSEADDR socket option **allows a socket to forcibly bind to a
>   port in use by another socket**. The second socket calls setsockopt with
>   the optname parameter set to SO_REUSEADDR and the optval parameter set
>   to a boolean value of TRUE before calling bind on the same port as the
>   original socket. Once the second socket has successfully bound, the
>   behavior for all sockets bound to that port is indeterminate. For
>   example, if all of the sockets on the same port provide TCP service,
>   any incoming TCP connection requests over the port cannot be
>   guaranteed to be handled by the correct socket — the behavior is
>   non-deterministic. A malicious program can use SO_REUSEADDR to
>   forcibly bind sockets already in use for standard network protocol
>   services in order to deny access to those service. No special
>   privileges are required to use this option.

Bonus reading: [What exactly does SO_REUSEADDR do?](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml) .

Answer (score 2):

It make no large sense to create multiple socket on one UDP port. UDP is not point 2 point protocol like TCP so using one "server" socket bind to specific port you can handle hundreds of clients.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can have multiple UDP sockets on one port if SO_REUSEADDR is specified via setsockopt.
However, I doubt that what you really need is using one UDP socket to communicate with multiple clients, which is also feasible. UDP is not connection-oriented, UDP APIs like sendto and recvfrom could distinguish different peers on one socket.